# What is the use of concurrency in run configuration of golangci-lint

Tags: go, concurrency, lint, golint

I'm adding some linting rules for my Go project with golangci-lint. I'm really confused about the concurrency field in it's run configurations. My understanding is that it will run the linting process in multiple thread so that the execution speed will increase. But I tried running linting with and without this concurrency configuration in my .golangci.yaml file but there is no significant changes in the execution time.

So what is the exact use of this configuaration ?

Example configuration can be found here [.golangci.yaml](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/blob/master/.golangci.example.yml)

Comment: If you have a large repo - many files and many subdirectories - the difference would be more pronounced.

Comment: It also depends on how many cores are available to it. If you're running it on a cloud runner with 1 VCPU, you cannot get any parallelism.